# In leaflet, how to set a marker to a fixed position on map?

Tags: javascript, gis, leaflet, mapbox, css-transforms

For example, I want to set a leaflet marker always pin to the bottom-right corner of the leaflet map.

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to approach this, depending on what you want to accomplish.

1. [This request](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90225/how-to-add-a-floating-crosshairs-icon-above-leaflet-map) for a centered "floating" crosshairs icon sounds very similar to your request. You essentially use `getCenter()` to create a fixed reference point, then use `setLatLng()` to update your marker's location relative to the map's center each time the user pans.
2. If the point you'd like to pin is purely cosmetic, you could just use HTML and CSS to position it on the page. [This example](https://www.mapbox.com/labs/blackbridge/flight-mh370/#6/7.177/104.403), which is also referenced in the previous example, uses CSS to position an icon within a span as a visual reference point, then takes advantage of `getCenter()` to add lat/lon values to the form on the left of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `getCenter()`, `getSize()`, and `L.marker()` to pin to the bottom-right.

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html